# What is the point of no return in Neptunia G?

Tags: megadimension-neptunia-v2

I've cleared the (first?) event in AffimaX base, but I haven't yet completed everything there is to do. I'd like to know what the point of no return is so I can face the third part of the game prepared (e.g. getting PR level 5 done in all cities).

Answer (score 1):

If you need a mixed party of CPUs and Candidates, the point of no return is now.

If you need to invest, the point of no return comes afterwards.

> If you need to do that, or have a party of CPUs, the point of no return is at the Dimensional Corridor.